# Is it possible to put an intransitive verb in passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice, intransitive-verbs, transitivity

My teacher told me that we can't convert intransitive verbs like 'walk' into passive voice when there is no object present. For example:

> He walks every day.

But I think we can convert this by saying:

> Walking is done by him every day.

Does this still count as passive voice? Also, is the second sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: It is a conversion of "Every day he does walking", not of the original sentence. "Walking" is being treated as a noun, while the original "walks" is a verb. In any case it is a very awkward sentence.

Comment: ***To walk*** can be used ***transitively***, as in *I walk the dog every day* - which can be "passivized" into *The dog **is walked** every day.*